# javascript get clicked link id and compare it with a string

Tags: javascript, string, hyperlink, compare

I'm new to JavaScript, I need some help  please!

I have these four links:
   `<a id="userName" href="javascript:showEditTextBox(this.id)"></a>
    <a id="occupation" href="javascript:showEditTextBox(this.id)"></a>
    <a id="country" href="javascript:showEditTextBox(this.id)"></a>
    <a id="industry" href="javascript:showEditTextBox(this.id)"></a>`

And I also have a div, with a p and a form element. The p id is: id="editHeader". 
What I want to do is, to change the p value, depending on which link was clicked. So I want to compare the clicked link's id value with a String:

My function is like so, but it doesn't work:

```
function showEditTextBox (id){
if(id == "userName") 
    document.getElementById("editHeader").innerHTML = 'Change username';
else if(id == "occupation") 
    document.getElementById("editHeader").innerHTML = 'Change occupation';
    else if(id == "country")
            document.getElementById("editHeader").innerHTML = 'Change country';
    else if(id == "industry")
            document.getElementById("editHeader").innerHTML = 'Change industry';
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using an `href` for this nor an `a` tag. Try using a `onclick` event handler.

Comment: press `f12` look at a debugger console (ff (firebug), chrome, ie)?

Comment: I have images inside these `a` tags, but `onclick` event doesn't work on `img`. How could I make this work else?

Comment: the `this` context in an href attribute is the `window` object...which has no `id` attribute

Comment: @LoganMurphy Oh ok...What could I use instead of `a` then?

Comment: it is `href` that is the issue...i will post code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use # as href and the onclick event. Like so. Otherwise your javascript is correct.

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FL7G8/1/

```
<a id="userName" href="#" onclick="showEditTextBox(this.id)">userName</a>
<a id="occupation" href="#" onclick="showEditTextBox(this.id)">occupation</a>
<a id="country" href="#" onclick="showEditTextBox(this.id)">country</a>
<a id="industry" href="#" onclick="showEditTextBox(this.id)">industry</a>
```

A cool effect would be to have href="#editHeader" for your anchor tags so that the window jumps to the element you are trying to change like so

```
<a id="industry" href="#editHeader" onclick="showEditTextBox(this.id)">industry</a>
```

Comment: Thanks.I considered this option, but this way href will add that `#` to the URL. Is there any better way, perhaps I should use divs instead of `a`?

Comment: You can exclude the `href="#"` completely and it will work...but the link will not show up blue or give you a pointer. However you can add your own css to fix this. `a[onclick] { cursor : pointer; color : blue; }` (updated the fiddle to include this)

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the links to be like the following:

```
<a id="userName" href="#" onClick="javascript:showEditTextBox(this.id)">username</a>
```

That should do it.